# Find in List<t> and return boolean if found

Tags: c#, linq

please excuse my ignorance am somewhat of a novice (but enthusiastically getting there)

```
public class MyType
{
    public string MyName;
    public string MyTown;
    public string MyJob;
}
```

I have a List of this type:

```
List<MyType> myVar = new List<MyType>()
```

Now I want to return a boolean based on this.  So for example:  Does `myVar` contain `MyName = "Bob"` and `MyJob = "Taxi Driver"`

I have managed to return all with a name of "Bob"

```
var e = myVar.Where(x => x.MyName== "Bob").ToList();
```

But I want to do something like:

```
bool mExists = (myVar.Where(x => x.MyName== "Bob" && MyJob="Taxi Driver").Count > 0) ? true : false;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`Any`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method.

```
bool exists = myVar.Any(x => x.MyName == "Bob" && x.MyJob == "Taxi Driver");
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid!  Thanks that's perfect!  Update: Not quite perfect, missing an x. and = but got me there! :P

Comment: @FlipTop Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @dcastro the code above won't even compile `bool exists = myVar.Any(x => x.MyName== "Bob" && MyJob="Taxi Driver");`, it should be `x.MyJob=="Taxi Driver"`

Comment: @ekad I already said that but it did tell me what I needed to know.  As dcastro was first to answer I feel I should mark his as accepted. Now I am not sure what I am meant to do :s

Comment: @ekad slight mistake, my bad! I've updated my answer. (PS: holy.. 2 downvotes because of that? excuse me for my horrible answer...)

Comment: @dcastro it's still not correct: `bool exists = myVar.Any(x => x.MyName== "Bob" && x.MyJob="Taxi Driver");`, you missed one `=`

Answer (score 7):

You can use [.Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx)

Example :

```
bool mExists = myVar.Any(x => x.MyName == "Bob" && x.MyJob == "Taxi Driver");
```

Comment: This is the best and most general solution, with Linq. But of course `List<>` itself has (since .NET 2.0) this functionality. That would be `bool mExists = myVar.Exists(x => x.MyName == "Bob" && x.MyJob == "Taxi Driver");`. Just for completeness. Documentation: [`List<>.Exists` instance method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx)